# kmplayer 64x keeps loading all my videos inside my folder/won't save settings

Tags: kmplayer

I have a folder with multiple files inside of it and every time i try to open ONE all the videos get put into the playlist when I specifically have "open selected files only" option on. Everytime I go into settings to see if I have the option selected it goes to "open similar files together". I have tried things people have posted like applying the settings and restarting my pc, install another version... all have failed i just want to watch my vids without it taking every one of the vids inside the folder and putting it into the playlist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.